# Should "DbContext" and "DbSet" be exposed for a pure POCO application

Tags: entity-framework

Can someone enlighten me about the intended (best-practice) use of "DbContext" and "DbSet" where data consumers should have no dependency on the EF whatsoever (100% POCO). While all the examples I find explain how to create POCO classes for the underlying data source (corresponding to RDBMS tables usually), they still expose "DbContext" and "DbSet" to the outside world (including MSFT's own examples on how to do data binding with these classes). This seems to defeat or (seriously) water down the benefits of using POCO. IOW, clients are still bound to the EF rather than a cleaner (IMHO) approach of creating some data store project that uses EF internally, but exposes only POCO to its users. Why do all articles on the EF seem to ignore this (am I missing something). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would usually create a service layer (based on the Repository pattern for example) that makes use of DbContext. Its role is to mediate between the database and the application/client. It will accept POCOs from the client and return POCOs to the client. That way, the client knows about the repository, but it doesn't know anything about DbContext.

Some more reading for you:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into these links but at first glance they appear to be nothing more than interface-based wrappers. That's fine, and it's probably the strategy I would have pursued anyway (or something like it), but I am curious why this type of approach isn't natively available in the EF itself. Only MSFT really knows, but it's a serious short-coming IMHO (the ORM itself isn't plug and play out-of-the-box).